# cloud_ml_engine scaleType implementation

Tags: deep-learning, google-cloud-ml, hyperparameters, scikits

I'm trying to implement the functionality of google cloud ml engine's hyperparameter tuning using scikit-optimize (skopt). I'm unsure how to consistently convert ml-engine's [scaleType](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/hyperparameter-tuning-overview) to [skopt.space.Real](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/space/space.m.html#skopt.space.space.Real)'s `prior`s.

Uniform is straight forward enough, and log-uniform *looks* to have an equivalent in each - but I'm not entirely sure the implementation is consistent. I'm also unsure how to implement ml engine's `UNIT_REVERSE_LOG_SCALE` if the `LOG_SCALE` is consistent with `skopt`'s `log-uniform` prior. The `log-uniform` distribution doesn't seem to behave as one might like for parameters away from `0` - e.g. if you want to scale between `0.9` and `0.999` the distribution is close to uniform (see first plot below).

Code and visualization using `skopt`s `log-uniform` and a couple of custom transformations below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import skopt


def sample_custom_log_uniform(min_val, max_val, n_samples):
    sample = skopt.space.uniform(0, 1).rvs(n_samples)
    return min_val + (10 ** sample - 1) / 9 *(max_val - min_val)


def sample_custom_reverse_log_uniform(min_val, max_val, n_samples):
    sample = skopt.space.uniform(0, 1).rvs(n_samples)
    return max_val - (10 ** sample - 1) / 9 *(max_val - min_val)


def sample(min_val, max_val, prior='log-uniform', n_samples=100000):
    if prior == 'custom-log-uniform':
        return sample_custom_log_uniform(min_val, max_val, n_samples)
    elif prior == 'custom-reverse-log-uniform':
        return sample_custom_reverse_log_uniform(min_val, max_val, n_samples)
    else:
        return skopt.space.Real(min_val, max_val, prior=prior).rvs(n_samples)


priors = (
    'log-uniform', 'custom-log-uniform', 'custom-reverse-log-uniform')
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, len(priors))
for (prior, ax) in zip(priors, axes):
    ax.hist(sample(0.9, 0.999, prior))
    ax.set_title(prior)
    ax.set_yticklabels([])

plt.show()
```

[image: distributions]

My questions are:

- does `ml engine` implement `LOG_SCALE` as `log-uniform` or `custom-log-uniform` from the above, or something else?
- does `ml engine` implement `REVERSE_LOG_SCALE` as `custom-reverse-log-uniform` above, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a parameter with feasible region [a, b]: `UNIT_LOG_SCALE` scales the feasible space logarithmically to [0, 1]. This maps a value x to log(x / a) / log(b / a). `UNIT_REVERSE_LOG_SCALE` scales the feasible space "reverse" logarithmically to [0, 1]. This maps a value x to 1.0 - log((b + a - x) / a) / log(b / a).

Answer (score 0):

Cloud ML Engine does not use scikit learn for its hyperparameter tuning, but rather custom implementations that allow us to provide state-of-the-art results.

Comment: I'm aware my own implementation won't be identical. I'm mostly just looking for a better understanding of what `REVERSE_LOG_SCALE` actually means. It's a question about the API, rather than the implementation.